# CentOS - why the systemctl service is executing twice?

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

CentOS 7.2, i have manually systemd file as below:

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/freeswitch.service
[Unit]
Description=freeswitch
After=syslog.target network.target local-fs.target

[Service]
; service
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/freeswitch/freeswitch.pid
Environment="DAEMON_OPTS=-nonat"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/freeswitch
ExecStart=/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch -u root -g daemon -ncwait -nonat

TimeoutSec=45s
Restart=always
; exec
User=root
Group=daemon
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitNOFILE=100000
LimitNPROC=60000
LimitSTACK=250000
LimitRTPRIO=infinity
LimitRTTIME=infinity
IOSchedulingClass=realtime
IOSchedulingPriority=2
CPUSchedulingPolicy=rr
CPUSchedulingPriority=89
UMask=0007

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But `systemctl start freeswitch` is not behaving properly, such as executing twice or while stop it keeps running when i do process query.

```
ps aux | grep freeswitch
root     31739  0.0  0.1 104552  3712 ?        Ss   20:46   0:00 /usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch -u root -g daemon -ncwait -nonat
root     31740  8.5  1.4 1148068 26508 ?       S<sl 20:46   0:00 /usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch -u root -g daemon -ncwait -nonat
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: **You** must ensure the pid of the daemon is put in the PIDFile for systemd to know what process to stop.

Comment: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/488038/47971281/ - Why this script works but above not?

Comment: If you don't specify a PIDFile, systemd will guess the pid of the server, usually correctly.

Comment: What is `systemctl status freeswitch.service` saying?